# Why does opencv not show a CV_32S image?

Tags: opencv

I am using OpenCV-4.2.0 (contrib). OpenCV does not show a labeled image created with connectedComponentsWithStats.

The relevant code is:

```
//Connected Compnents
std::cout << "Calculating Connected Components..." << std::endl;
Mat background_mask_labels(background_mask.size(), CV_32S);
Mat cc_stats,cc_centroids;
int nLabels = cv::connectedComponentsWithStats(background_mask, background_mask_labels, cc_stats, cc_centroids, 4);

// show output
imshow("Background Image", background_mask);
imshow("Background Labels", background_mask_labels);
waitKey(0);
```

When running the program in x64 Debug mode it throws an error:

```
OpenCV(4.2.0) Error: Assertion failed (src_depth != CV_16F && src_depth != CV_32S) in convertToShow, file c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\highgui\src\precomp.hpp, line 137
```

at

```
imshow("Background Labels", background_mask_labels);
```

But I dont't understand the error, since I declared background_mask_labels to be CV_32S in first place.
Even a `background_mask_labels.convertTo(background_mask_labels , CV_32S);` after the connectedComponents does not help - same output.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Is `background_mask_labels` the source image?

Comment: `background_mask_labels` should be the labeled output image

Comment: The error specifies `src_depth`.